# Spinner not occupying the full width of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I am having a relativeLayout and thats a spinner which i hope it occupies all along horizontally on the monitor, here's some info of it.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:minHeight="45dp"
android:background="@drawable/background">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

with adapter correspondingly set like this

```
        @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (view == null) {
        view   = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(view);

        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }return view;}
```

and this works perfectly fine on most of the phones i tested with.
**See image 1**

**Yet on one of the ASUS phone (**See image 2**)
the spinner is having a margin all around it for like around 10dp thick.**

**What caused the problem??**

please let me know if any of you need extra info of it, thanks.

---

additional info.:

```
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/floor_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/line"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:dropDownSelector="@color/black"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="45dp"
    >

</Spinner>
```

maybe there is some misunderstanding, this is the spinner marked in red and it should be fitting the whole width (and actually also the top vertical distance. 
No Gap is existing between the spinner and the edge of the monitor.

**Image 1**
[image]
but on the ASUS phone there are gap/margins existing between the spinner and the edge of the monitor/the top title banner.

**Image 2**
[image]

Comment: where is your spinner?? i don't see it.

Comment: @OnkarNene oh i mean the pulldown menu, isn't it be called the spinner??

Comment: @Terrance, in Android drop down list is called as spinner.. It's a part of widget.. you can see it in layout's drag-drop menu

Comment: @OnkarNene sir i've added some remarks on the photos, please check and see if you can help. Thanks a lot.